# How do i use multiple XML layouts in a single activity without having to create so many activities

Tags: android, layout

I am creating a project that would involved multiple activities.Is there a way to create multiple layout within a single activity and set intents for the layouts using the java class of the same main activity from which the layout files were created. please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the use of fragments help if you don’t want to finish the activity? Simply place a frameLayout inside the activity XML and use fragment Transactions to replace the frameLayout view with a fragments XML file? This will result in needing to create multiple XML files but all will be usable in a single Activity